# How to write my own custom TTS engine app in android?

Tags: android, text-to-speech, freetts

I have to write my own custom TTS engine so that i can use it in my Apps. Why I want to create my own TTS engine because some of the TTS engine either doesn't support required languages OR those which are supported are not free TTS engine, so I will create my own engine with all those languages supported, I Just want to create it as a library(.jar) so it will easy to add to several applications.

Can anyone suggest me how to achieve it OR is it possible to achieve it, if yes then how? please assist me to implement it.

Comment: I can use that but problem is all devices doesn't support the required languages, most of devices are Pico installed in it and Pico by default supports only 5 languages and if I am going to install some other TTS , those are not free so I thought better to create my own TTS engine and make use of it.

Answer (score 3):

Not likely to be a weekend project ;-)

Pico is apparently [open source](https://groups.google.com/forum/?fromgroups=#!topic/android-platform/Lpab5nVEI-c) or you could check out these other [open source projects](http://www.babelfish.org/tts-free.htm) and see if any of them can give you a running start.

You would also have to create your own sound files which is not at all trivial and quite beyond the scope of SO.

Good luck though!